# How to set timezone in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have setup Azure Cosmos DB, and saved telemetry data. But the timezone it is using is Central Standard Time. I want to set to IST, any option in Azure Cosmos DB to change this timezone? or I should create new database in required timezone.

Comment: There is no notion of time zone for Cosmos DB. Not sure where you saw timezone being Central, but that's not the case. If you're referring to `_ts`, that's epoch time (which is UTC). It's true that you may deploy a Cosmos DB instance within a given region, but that is strictly about which data center(s) the database is deployed to.

Comment: I am having difficulty in querying data. I am in IST, but _ts is in UTC, what is the right way query record based on date

Comment: The Cosmos DB docs address this directly. Just store everything as UTC and convert as necessary (for example, the C# SDK has `UnixDateTimeConverter`). Storing in anything other than UTC is just going to cause issues for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the data you are creating, the [recommended practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates#storing-datetimes) is to store all datetime values as ISO 8601 strings in the UTC time zone. This way there is no ambiguity about the time when data is read later.

I would also consider storing the [IANA time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) ID alongside the datetime value, so you can convert back to local time and between time zones reliably.

Comment: This _ts is auto generated, how to set timezone for this
`{
    "measurementsCount": 1,
    "averageTemperature": 28,
    "averageHumidity": 62,
    "id": "d88beda5-0ff7-41de-8c41-fcd8fe349f39",
    "_rid": "70UIAJjRjbUBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/70UIAA==/colls/70UIAJjRjbU=/docs/70UIAJjRjbUBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"2b00e02d-0000-0700-0000-5f6c3b3e0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1600928574
}`

Comment: It's typical to convert the time you are querying for to UTC first in the client before issuing the query. It's probably never a good idea to store a local time, rather than a UTC time plus time zone ID. You can also add your own time field, and ignore the automatic _ts field.